# Return an array of structs from a class, modify the array and update it inside the class

Tags: c#, struct

I would like to return an array of structs from a class, modify the content of the structs outside the class, but have the structs inside the class updated as well. In the following I will provide some background information:

I want to periodically read data from an external PLC, a `ReadDataFromPlc` function is provided from an external library. That function needs an array of structs as one of its parameters, that struct is also defined in that external library. It contains a handle to a PLC variable to be read, a byte array where the result will be written to, and an integer resultCode:

```
namespace extLib {
  public struct RWstruct {
    public IntPtr AccessHandle;    // Handle to the data to be read
    public byte[] Buffer;          // the read data will be written here
    public int ResultCode;
  }

  public static int ReadDataFromPlc(RWstruct[] symbolicRW){
    // modify the Buffer in each of the structs
  }
}
```

In my program I have created a tree structure that holds, among other things, a representation of the data structure in the PLC, with groups and sub-groups etc. where the depth is unknown at compile time. Each leaf of the tree contains one RWstruct.

```
class Node {
  private string _name;
  private bool _leaf;
  private RWstruct _rwStruct;     // if the node is a leaf, it contains an rwStruct
  private List<Node> _childNodes; // a node either has childNodes, or is a leaf

  // function to return all rwStructs from this node and all child nodes.
  public List<RWstruct> GetRWStructList(){
    List<RWstruct> returnList = new();
    if (_leaf){
      returnList.Add(_rwStruct);  // add the member rwStruct to be returned
    } else { // node has children, recursively return all rwStructs
      foreach(Node childNode in _childNodes){
        returnList.AddRange(childNode.getRWStructList());
    }
    return returnList;
  }
}
```

Once I have a complete tree, I have to retrieve all the structs from the leafs of that tree and store them in a single array, that array can then be passed to the `ReadDataFromPlc` function:

```
Node completeTree = getCompleteTree(); // the completeTree has an unknown structure

// get all RWstructs from the leafs into one array:
RWstruct[] rwStructArray = completeTree.GetRWStructList().ToArray();
// maybe the List.ToArray() is the culprit, since the description of ToArray says "copies"?

// read data from the PLC, this function will be called e.g. every second when a timer fires.
extLib.ReadDataFromPlc(rwStructArray);
```

So far this works, the `ReadDataFromPlc` function modifies the RWstructs in the `rwStructArray`. However, I would also like the RWstruct inside the leafes of the tree to be modified. Curiously, the `byte[] Buffer` is updated in the leafes automatically, but the `int ResultCode` is not, as shown in the following table. I'm assuming this has to to with the fact that arrays are automatically referenced but ints are copied?

|  | rwStructArray outside tree | Node._rwStruct inside tree |
| --- | --- | --- |
| before `ReadDataFromPLC` | `byte[] Buffer = [0, 0]` `int ResultCode = 0` | `byte[] Buffer = [0, 0]` `int ResultCode = 0` |
| after `ReadDataFromPLC` | `byte[] Buffer = [1, 3]` `int ResultCode = 1` | `byte[] Buffer = [1, 3]` `int ResultCode =` **`0`** |

My question is, is there an elegant way of keeping the RWstructs inside the leafes up to date?
I'm thinking maybe the fact that my `GetRWStructList` function returns a list, that is then converted to an array is the problem, since the description of `ToArray` says "copies the elements of the List to a new array.". Would it make a difference if the function returned an array? How would that look with the recursive depth-first tree traversal?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

**Edit**: based on the suggestion by ThatGuy I have created a Node member function to return all the leafs, then copy all RWstructs to the rwStructArray, use it for reading data, and afterwards copy the RWstructs from the array back to the leafs in the flat list, which are references, so the leafes inside the tree are updated as well.

```
leafList = completeTree.getLeafList()   // returns a list of all leafs
for (int i=0; i<leafList.Count(); i++){ // copy the structs to the flat array
  rwStructArray[i] = leafList[i]._rwStruct;
}

extLib.ReadDataFromPlc(rwStructArray); // read data from Plc and modify the rwstructs inside the array

// copy rwStructs back to leafs
for (int i=0; i<leafList.Count(); i++){
  leafList[i]._rwStruct = rwStructArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the buffer is updated throughout the program but the structs in the nodes are not is because an array is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) and a struct is a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types).

Because of value type semantics, they are copied everywhere unless passed by reference using the `ref` keyword. Here's a basic example:

```cs
public static void Fn(int x) { x = 0; }
```

Mutating `x` inside of the above function does not mutate `x` anywhere outside of the function. However, the function below *will* mutate the source of `x`:

```cs
public static void Fn(ref int x) { x = 0; }
```

Because classes are reference types, any mutations to those objects will be reflected throughout the entire program. They are not copied when passed as an argument unlike a struct.

A workaround would be to retrieve all of the nodes containing the structs you want to mutate and then mutate the structs through accessing the node or simply making the struct a class instead. After all, the struct is larger than 16 bytes on a 64-bit system.

Comment: I like the idea of retrieving all the leafs, I have implemented a function that does that, then I copy the RWstruct of each leaf into the rwStructArray I need for the external `ReadDataFromPlc` function and afterwards I can copy the structs back into the leafs in the flat list, which are reference and therefore also updates the nodes inside the tree.

Comment: I cannot use classes instead of the structs, because the external library function, which I have no control over, needs the array of structs.